# ValueError: None values not supported (optimizer)

Tags: python, optimization, keras

I made a simple auto-encoder for image forgeries detection. However, when I tried to change, in compile:

```
optimizer='adam'
```

into

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False),
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: None values not supported. I don't know why, because it works well in the first case !

I hope you could help me.

Comment: You should include full source code and error messages, if not nobody can say anything with so little information.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `epsilon=None`? --- If this is not the problem, them you've got a loss function that is not differentiable, or unused weights in some custom layer, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your version of Keras. Before 2.1.3, `None` was not a valid value for the argument `epsilon`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it !